# Unable to Modify Margins on Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using the Lyrical theme on wordpress. It is a free theme by godaddy. I want to let the main take up the whole width of the page, so I believe that is essentially removing the `body.site` margins. I realize there are many related questions on different themes and I have tried the suggested solutions including:

```
#main {
    max-width:300%
    width:1500px;
    left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
}

body.site {
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#page {
    max-width:100%
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left:0;
    left:0;
}
```

The `#main` styling worked a little bit. I was able to increase the width of the main as desired, but because the margins were still there, it was not centered. None of the margin stylings worked. I looked through the theme's style.css as best I could. It's difficult to debug as it's 4000+ lines long and since css uses a kind of chain styling, I can't leverage searches very well, because there are many instances of 'margin' and '.site' ect.

**My question:** What code is missing to target the margins and eliminate them?

Note: I think stackoverflow is the most suitable place to consult, that way more users can see and learn from this all-too-common issue.

Update: Here is a screenshot of when I clicked inspect element on the margin. I tried everything in `#page` attributes as well as site-header-wrapper. Perhaps someone will see something I'm missing:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share something more... like html and other associated css. By looking into only these three css blocks, it's hard to understand.

Comment: If your website is hosted online, could you share its URL so I can check and suggest you the changes.

Comment: all files can be found in [this](https://github.com/godaddy/wp-lyrical-theme) repository. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help.

Comment: Better provide your site adress

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not permitted to share the site I'm developing for at the moment, but after some digging I found an example site with the theme [here](https://wpnux.godaddy.com/?theme=lyrical&header_image=http%3A%2F%2Fisteam.wsimg.com%2Fstock%2Fd29000d8c83f595defeaa4f50483a9c36a77ac4fd090fcc186b02efdf5bd88cb).

Answer (score 1):

try adding !important to your CSS. But before adding try to inspect element and add style for the accurate result and try a different style that does not necessarily need !important.

```
#main {
        max-width:300% !important;
        width:1500px !important;
        left:0px !important;
        padding-left:0px !important;
    }

    body.site {
        max-width:100% !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
    }

    #page {
        max-width:100% !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
        padding-left:0 !important;
        left:0 !important;
    }
```

Comment: great idea, however the margin's are still there. How perplexing

Comment: did you try doing an inspect element to it? and remove any margin?

Comment: yes, I looked at the element. According to that the margin has an `id=page`. However even after focusing on `#page` and its child attributes, I can't make it go away. I provided a link to an example website, are you getting different results than me?

Comment: hmm.. I think you're editing the wrong element. try editing in the "site-header-wrapper" element maybe that will be the right element.